# What is the fastest 4-seater car in Grand Theft Auto V Story Mode?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

For a good getaway vehicle, which is the fastest 4-seater car in *Grand Theft Auto V* Story Mode (not *GTA Online*)?

As @turbo mentions in the comments below acceleration is also an important consideration.

Comment: note that acceleration and handling are probably more important for a getaway vehicle, as you can rarely outrun the cops by just gunning it in a straight line.  Chances are you won't even hit top speed while evading.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've just discovered and trawled through this helpful site which lists all of the GTA5 vehicles: https://googledrive.com/host/0B-Q7WnzcPvLtLVVoM3otTVlnOFE/all.htm

It looks like the faster 4 seater is the Ubermacht Oracle 1 - with a speed of "8.1" and an acceleration of "6.8". Although there are many cars with a speed of "8.0" (but not as good acceleration).

[image: Ubermacht Oracle 1 specs]

After a bit more homework I've also identified these two cars - the Bravado Buffalo (cheap and plentiful) and the Dewbauchee Exemplar having very similar speed and acceleration stats - but better traction:

[image: Bravado Buffalo specs]

[image: Dewbauchee Exemplar specs]

I should add that after months of playing the game my "go to" 4-door is the [Lampadati Felon](http://gta.wikia.com/Felon) for it's handling. The Felon is rare but stealable so can be used as the primary car from the beginning of the GTA Online campaign.

It is also worth noting that as of the [I'm Not a Hipster Update](http://gta.wikia.com/I%27m_Not_a_Hipster_Update), the Bravado Buffalo S, or Franklin's Buffalo, can be purchased from [southernsanandreassuperautos.com](http://gta.wikia.com/Southernsanandreassuperautos.com) for $96,000. It has the same stats as the Dewbauchee Exemplar, but a faster acceleration at "7.5".
http://gta5.consolegameswiki.com/wiki/Bravado_Buffalo_(Franklin)

Answer (score 2):

##### Top Speed

The fastest 4-seater car in *GTA V* story mode is the **[Dewbauchee Exemplar](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Exemplar)** at 117.25 mph (188.70 km/h). (Note: Not counting *GTA Online* cars that can only be used in story mode if the game is modded.)

The second fastest is the [Bravado Sprunk Buffalo](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Sprunk_Buffalo) at 116.00 mph (186.68 km/h), while the third-fastest is the [Karin Sultan](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Sultan) at 115.75 mph (186.28 km/h).

This is according to vehicle testing by [Broughy1322](https://broughy.com/), who [tests vehicle top speed](https://gtacars.net/gta5/topspeed) by driving them on a straight road.

##### Lap Time

Broughy1322 also tests vehicle lap times by driving them around a circuit, rather than a straight road. Aside from top speed, this also takes the vehicle stats: acceleration, handling, traction, braking, and weight, among other stats, more into consideration.

The 4-seater car with the fastest lap time in *GTA V* story mode is the [**Karin Sultan**](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Sultan) (1:05.834), followed by the [Bravado Sprunk Buffalo](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Sprunk_Buffalo) (1:07.234), and then the [Bravado Buffalo S](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Buffalo_S) (Franklin's car) (1:08.001).

---

The cars' stats:

|  | Exemplar | Sprunk Buffalo | Sultan | Buffalo S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Top Speed | 117.25 mph (188.70 km/h) | 116.00 mph (186.68 km/h) | 115.75 mph (186.28 km/h) | 112.25 mph (180.65 km/h) |
| Lap Time | 1:08.369 | 1:07.234 | 1:05.834 | 1:08.001 |

Broughy1322's testing takes the game's physics into account, as opposed to just getting the stats from the game files which is less indicative of actual top speed or lap time. See his webpage (linked below) for a detailed explanation and videos of his vehicle testing methodology.

Sources:

- [Broughy1322 - GTA V Vehicle Info, Performance & Tier Lists](https://gtacars.net/gta5/tiers)
- [Broughy1322's top speed testing methodology](https://gtacars.net/gta5/topspeed)
- [Broughy1322's lap time testing methodology](https://gtacars.net/gta5/laptime)
- [GTABase.com - all GTA V story mode 4-seater cars sorted by top speed](https://www.gtabase.com/grand-theft-auto-v/vehicles/#sort=attr.ct132.frontend_value&sortdir=desc&attr.ct1.value=commercial%2Ccompacts%2Ccoupes%2Cindustrial%2Cmotorcycles%2Cmilitary%2Cmuscle%2Coff-road%2Copen-wheel%2Crc%2Csedans%2Cservice%2Csports%2Csports-classic%2Csuper%2Csuvs%2Ctuners%2Cutility%2Cvans&attr.ct11.value=4%2C16&attr.ct5.value=gta5-story&page=1)
- [GTABase.com - all GTA V story mode 4-seater cars sorted by lap time](https://www.gtabase.com/grand-theft-auto-v/vehicles/#sort=attr.ct533.frontend_value&sortdir=asc&attr.ct1.value=commercial%2Ccompacts%2Ccoupes%2Cindustrial%2Cmotorcycles%2Cmilitary%2Cmuscle%2Coff-road%2Copen-wheel%2Crc%2Csedans%2Cservice%2Csports%2Csports-classic%2Csuper%2Csuvs%2Ctuners%2Cutility%2Cvans&attr.ct11.value=4%2C16&attr.ct5.value=gta5-story&page=1)

Answer (score 1):

Felon it handles pretty well and has a higher acceleration than the oracle and sultan and has a better top speed than the sultan.

Answer (score 0):

Karin Sultan fully modified. In a straight line with enough space it will go eventually faster than an Adder.

Answer (score 0):

The Obey tailgater is a nice handling car and can be brought in to online mode by the tutorial

The tailgater is a nice car fully modified and can be a nice 4 seat car for you.

Answer (score 0):

If prefer the tailgater it has good speed and acleration so you can find it when Simeon wants it or can bring it online

Answer (score -1):

As of heists in my opinion the Karin Kuruma beats all of them it goes fast, is bulletproof and is an overall beast.

Comment: The Karin Kuruma is not available in *GTA V* story mode. It's a *GTA Online*-only car.