# What is the fastest car in GTA V Story Mode, and where can I find it?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

What car is the fastest (when upgraded) in *GTA V* Story Mode (not *GTA Online*) and where can I find it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[The Truffade Adder has a stock speed of "8.6" - which makes it the fastest car in GTA V.](https://googledrive.com/host/0B-Q7WnzcPvLtLVVoM3otTVlnOFE/super.htm)

However I prefer the Overflod Entity XF as it has significantly better acceleration and traction - which matters more than top speed IMO.

[image]

Both cars will occasionally spawn in the game world (generally around the richer areas of Los Santos) but if you do steal one you cannot "own" it. The Adder spawns frequently in front of [Sessanta Nove at Portola Drive, Rockford Hills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CieWy.jpg).

To own one of these cars you need to buy them from Legendarymotorsport.net - and they're expensive with the Adder at $1,000,000 and the Entity XF at $795,000

It's reported that you can own the Entity XF via the mission "[I Fought the Law](http://gta.wikia.com/I_Fought_the_Law...)" but this seems like an exploit of sorts.

[If you want a fast, affordable vehicle, buy/steal a motorbike.](https://googledrive.com/host/0B-Q7WnzcPvLtLVVoM3otTVlnOFE/motorcycles.htm)

If you want a fast car you can buy or steal, have a look at the Schyster Fusilade:
[image]

And if you want a fast 4 seater car check out my question about that here: [What is the fastest 4 seater car in Grand Theft Auto 5?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139301/what-is-the-fastest-4-seater-car-in-grand-theft-auto-5)

Comment: You can own the Adder if you steal it. Just modify the car or park it in your garage. Then it's yours.

Comment: Is this answer still valid for the PC (PS4/XBone) version? I heard that some cars have been added and maybe the changed some attributes.

Answer (score 4):

##### Top Speed

The fastest car in *GTA V* story mode is the [Vapid **Pißwasser Dominator**](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Pi%C3%9Fwasser_Dominator) at 126.50 mph (203.58 km/h).* It is only available in the Enhanced Edition of the game (PC, PS4, PS5, Xbox One, and Xbox Series X/S versions). It can be acquired by winning the third [stock car race](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Stock_Car_Racing).

<sup>* Not counting GTA Online cars that can only be used in story mode if the game is modded.</sup>

The second fastest car is the [Truffade **Z-Type**](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Z-Type) at 126.25 mph (203.18 km/h). The Z-Type is the fastest car on the PS3 and Xbox 360 versions of *GTA V* since the Pißwasser Dominator cannot be acquired on those versions. The third fastest car is the [Truffade **Adder**](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Adder) at 124.75 mph (200.77 km/h).

This is according to vehicle testing by [Broughy1322](https://broughy.com/), who [tests vehicle top speed](https://gtacars.net/gta5/topspeed) by driving them on a straight road.

|  | Vapid Pißwasser Dominator | Truffade Z-Type | Truffade Adder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Top Speed | 126.50 mph (203.58 km/h) | 126.25 mph (203.18 km/h) | 124.75 mph (200.77 km/h) |
| Lap Time | 1:06.766 | 1:09.368 | 1:04.964 |
| Story Mode price | n/a | $10,000,000 | $1,000,000 |

##### Lap Time

Broughy1322 also [tests vehicle lap times](https://gtacars.net/gta5/laptime) by driving them around a circuit, rather than a straight road. This provides a more balanced understanding of a car's performance. Rather than just top speed, this takes the vehicle stats: acceleration, handling, traction, braking, and weight, among other stats and factors, more into consideration.

The car with the fastest lap time in *GTA V* story mode is the [Pegassi **Zentorno**](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Zentorno) at 1:00.960. It can be purchased from Legendary Motorsport for $725,000. It can also be found [parked at various locations or driven by NPCs.](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Zentorno#Locations) It has a chance of spawning at the Burton, LSIA, and La Mesa branches of Los Santos Customs.

The car with the second fastest lap time is the [Progen **T20**](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/T20) at 1:01.287, followed by the [Pegassi **Osiris**](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Osiris) 1:01.394.

|  | Pegassi Zentorno | Progen T20 | Pegassi Osiris |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lap Time | 1:00.960 | 1:01.287 | 1:01.394 |
| Top Speed | 122.00 mph (196.34 km/h) | 122.25 mph (196.74 km/h) | 122.00 mph (196.34 km/h) |
| Story mode price | $725,000 | $2,200,000 | $1,950,000 |

---

Broughy1322's testing takes the game's physics into account, as opposed to just getting the stats from the game files which is less indicative of actual top speed or lap time. See his webpage (linked below) for a detailed explanation and videos of his vehicle testing methodology.

Sources:

- [Broughy1322 - *GTA V* Vehicle Info, Performance & Tier Lists](https://gtacars.net/gta5/tiers)
- [Broughy1322's top speed testing methodology](https://gtacars.net/gta5/topspeed)
- [Broughy1322's lap time testing methodology](https://gtacars.net/gta5/laptime)
- [GTABase.com - all *GTA V* story mode cars sorted by top speed](https://www.gtabase.com/grand-theft-auto-v/vehicles/#sort=attr.ct132.frontend_value&sortdir=desc&attr.ct1.value=commercial%2Ccompacts%2Ccoupes%2Cindustrial%2Cmilitary%2Cmuscle%2Coff-road%2Copen-wheel%2Crc%2Csedans%2Cservice%2Csports%2Csports-classic%2Csuper%2Csuvs%2Ctuners%2Cutility%2Cvans&attr.ct5.value=gta5-story&page=1)
- [GTABase.com - all *GTA V* story mode cars sorted by lap time](https://www.gtabase.com/grand-theft-auto-v/vehicles/#sort=attr.ct533.frontend_value&sortdir=asc&attr.ct1.value=commercial%2Ccompacts%2Ccoupes%2Cindustrial%2Cmilitary%2Cmuscle%2Coff-road%2Copen-wheel%2Crc%2Csedans%2Cservice%2Csports%2Csports-classic%2Csuper%2Csuvs%2Ctuners%2Cutility%2Cvans&attr.ct5.value=gta5-story&page=1)