# What's the fastest car in Grand Theft Auto Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

The fastest car in *GTA V* story mode is listed in this question: [What is the fastest car in GTA 5, and where can I find it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/143874/what-is-the-fastest-car-in-gta-5-and-where-can-i-find-it)

But, since *GTA Online* has so many cars than *GTA V*, and *GTA Online* even got an F1-style car (which I think is the fastest?)... So, what's the fastest car in *GTA Online*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Top Speed

In the *GTA Online* Expanded & Enhanced Edition (PS5 and Xbox Series X/S), the fastest car is the Declasse **[Vigero ZX](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Vigero_ZX)** (HSW) (157.5 mph). The Vigero ZX, [among other cars](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Hao%27s_Special_Works#Conversions), is exclusive to the E&E Edition. The reason for the E&E Edition-exclusive cars' superior performance is that they can be converted to a higher performance version, the "HSW Performance Upgrade", at [Hao's Special Works](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Hao%27s_Special_Works), a mod shop exclusive to the E&E Edition.

In the *GTA Online* Enhanced Edition (PC, PS4, and Xbox One), the fastest car is the Grotti [**Vigilante**](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Vigilante_(car)) (147 mph), a weaponized, rocket-boosted car.

The fastest non-weaponized, non-rocket boosted car in *GTA Online* Enhanced Edition is the BF **[Weevil Custom](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Weevil_Custom)** (137.5 mph).

These are all according to vehicle testing by [Broughy1322](https://broughy.com/), who [tests vehicle top speed](https://gtacars.net/gta5/topspeed) by driving them on a straight road.

##### Lap Time

Broughy1322 also tests vehicle lap times by driving them around a circuit, rather than a straight road. This also takes the vehicle stats: acceleration, handling, traction, braking, and weight, among other stats, more into consideration.

The *GTA Online* car with the fastest lap time is the Benefactor **[BR8](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/BR8)** (0:54.788) (121 mph), a Formula One car.

The *GTA Online* car with the second fastest lap time is the Pegassi **[Weaponized Ignus](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Weaponized_Ignus)** (HSW) (0:55.589) (146.25 mph), which is exclusive to the Expanded & Enhanced Edition (PS5 and Xbox Series X/S).

---

Broughy1322's testing takes the game's physics into account, as opposed to just getting the stats from the game files which is less indicative of actual top speed or lap time. See his webpage (linked below) for a detailed explanation and videos of his vehicle testing methodology.

Sources:

- [Broughy1322 - GTA Online Vehicle Info, Performance & Tier Lists](https://gtacars.net/gta5/tiers)
- [Broughy1322's top speed testing methodology](https://gtacars.net/gta5/topspeed)
- [Broughy1322's lap time testing methodology](https://gtacars.net/gta5/laptime)
- [GTACars.net - all GTA Online cars sorted by top speed](https://gtacars.net/gta5?page=1&sort=top_speed&filter_vehicle_type=car&filter_vehicle_type=submarinecar)
- [GTACars.net - all GTA Online cars sorted by lap time](https://gtacars.net/gta5?page=1&sort=lap_time&filter_vehicle_type=car&filter_vehicle_type=submarinecar)

Comment: Even though I've stopped playing GTAV, I'm kinda jealous to E&E edition. Wonder why Rockstar isn't upgrading PC version. Well... they don't care much about PC version user according to their attitude against cheaters, I think I get the reason...

Answer (score 1):

In GTA online the fastest car is the Vigilante with the top speed of 147 mph. You can check out a full list of all vehicles top speeds and other info here:
[Broughy1322](https://broughy.com/gta5carsoverview)

Comment: Ah, the Vigilante. Then what would be the fastest car that is able to put in to garage? I... think I'm a bit dumb, that site is not so user friendly.

Comment: As I remember you can buy the Vigilante and place it in a garage you own. Or you mean a car that you can steal and put it in your garage?

Comment: Uh, no. I think I misremembered as something, indeed it can be put in to garage. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that this does use the boost, and its top speed is significantly lower. the fastest car without boost is the Pariah, with 136 mph.