# Fastest Car in Grand Theft Auto V PC

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

Since the other question [Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139301/what-is-the-fastest-4-seater-car-in-grand-theft-auto-5) is out of date, and I can't comment on them, ill ask a new question.

What are the fastest to date 4 seater and 2 seater cars available to purchase in Grand Theft Auto V at 27th April 2015?

Edit;

> Since its 2015 and most of the flagged duplicate posts haven't been
>   touched since 2014, I'm pretty sure my post is relevant, if not kindly
>   tell me how to "bump" a post for up to date answers.

Comment: We don't allow duplicate questions, regardless of the age of the previous one.  That's what updating answers are for.

Comment: Zacharia, there is no bumping in Arqade. When you earn more reputation, you'll be able to start bounties on older questions to more emphatically ask for updates.